# how to use custom font in views that extended from appCompat Views

Tags: android

i have wired problem with use custom font

i created new library in my project for set custom font on some views and it worked correctly recently but now it does not work and write this error in some api

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.noin.noinkala/ir.noin.noinkala.Activity.ActivationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #85: Error inflating class ir.noin.noincf.NoinCFEditText
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #85: Error inflating class ir.noin.noincf.NoinCFEditText
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noinkala.Activity.ActivationActivity.onCreate(ActivationActivity.java:53)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noinkala.Activity.ActivationActivity.onCreate(ActivationActivity.java:53) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_phone.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020098
>                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
>                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:806)
>                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noincf.NoinCFEditText.(NoinCFEditText.java:16)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noinkala.Activity.ActivationActivity.onCreate(ActivationActivity.java:53) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                       Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
>                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
>                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
>                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
>                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
>                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:806) 
>                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:62) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:58) 
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noincf.NoinCFEditText.(NoinCFEditText.java:16) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                          at ir.noin.noinkala.Activity.ActivationActivity.onCreate(ActivationActivity.java:53) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

one my custom view classes is

```
package ir.noin.noincf;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


public class NoinCFEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

  public NoinCFEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setupView(null);
  }

  public NoinCFEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setupView(attrs);
  }

  public NoinCFEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int     defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.setupView(attrs);
  }

  private void setupView(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
      TypedArray attributes = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NoinCFCustomAttr);

      try {
    int font = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.NoinCFCustomAttr_font, NoinCFTypeProvider.IRANIANSANS_NORMAL);
    switch (font) {
      case NoinCFTypeProvider.IRANIANSANS_NORMAL:
        setTypeface(NoinCFTypeProvider.getIraniansans(getContext()));
        break;
      case NoinCFTypeProvider.IRANIANSANS_LIGHT:
        setTypeface(NoinCFTypeProvider.getIraniansansLight(getContext()));
        break;
      case NoinCFTypeProvider.IRANIANSANS_BOLD:
        setTypeface(NoinCFTypeProvider.getIraniansansBold(getContext()));
        break;
    }
  } finally {
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
    attributes.recycle();
  }

}
  }
}
```

provider class

```
public class NoinCFTypeProvider {

  public static final int IRANIANSANS_NORMAL=0;
  public static final int IRANIANSANS_LIGHT=1;
  public static final int IRANIANSANS_BOLD=2;

  private static Typeface iraniansans;
  private static Typeface iraniansansBold;
  private static Typeface iraniansansLight;


  public static Typeface getIraniansans(Context context){
if (iraniansans==null){
  iraniansans=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"iransans.ttf");
}
return iraniansans;
  }

  public static Typeface getIraniansansBold(Context context){
if (iraniansansBold==null){
  iraniansansBold=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"iransans_Bold.ttf");
}
return iraniansansBold;
  }

      public static Typeface getIraniansansLight(Context context){
if (iraniansansLight==null){
  iraniansansLight=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"iransans_Light.ttf");
}
return iraniansansLight;
  }



}
```

and my xml file contain

```
  <ir.noin.noincf.NoinCFEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_activation_phone"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19"/>
```

it crashed under api 22 and it crashed when it run first time in api 25

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace.  You posted the least useful part/

Comment: Also, you don't need, or really want to invalidate or request layout in the constructor.  It isn't fully setup yet-  no parent has been set etc.

Comment: i add full of stck trace

Comment: "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector at" are you running on a version of Android that supports vector drawbacks? If not, you have to use the back ported methods for them